# Open .gof files

Tags: r

I would like to open some .gof files in R, to eventually merge them and create a dataframe. Could someone help me with the code?
Here is an example of .gof I will want to open and merge: https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/index.php/s/gOwjNM9o7O86Gob

Thank you very much!

Comment: No way I'm clicking a random cloud storage link. Maybe give a little background on what a .gof file is and a link to an official aarnet, .gov.au or similar site that hosts some example files.

Comment: But it's an `.edu.au` domain, so it *must* be legitimate ...

Answer (score 0):

For all I can tell, these are some sort of obscure CAD/3D files. Open the files in the application they were generated and try to export to a different format, preferably a CSV. I could not find any package or way to open these files in R as they are now.